# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error in main method

Tags: java, string, exception, charat

I am obtaining a StringIndexOutOfBoundsError when running my main method.

Here is the output of my program in the command line.

```
"Please enter the shift, 1 for day, 2 for night"

 1

"you entered a number for the shift"

"Please enter the hourly pay Rate"

 2

"you entered a number for the pay Rate"

"Please enter the employees name"

 brenda

 "cat6b" 
"your value you entered is correct 0-9 or a - z"

"Please enter the employee number"

 100e

 "cat41"

"your value you entered is correct 0-9 or a - z"

"Please enter current date in XXYYZZZZ format, X is day, Y is month, Z is year"

 10203933

 "cat81 "

"your value you entered is correct 0-9 or a - z"

 90 1

 valye of array is 1

 81 0

 value of array is 0

 82 2

 value of array is 2

 83 0

 value of array is 0

 84 3

 value of array is 3

 85 9

 value of array is 9

 86 3

 value of array is 3

 87 3

 value of array is 3

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of 

range: 8

 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)

 at ProductionWorker<init>(ProductionWorker.java:66)

 at labBookFiftyFour.main(labBookFiftyFour.java:58)"

"Press any key to continue . . ."
```

Ignore the cat parts in the code, i was using a println statement to test the code. Ignore the value of array output as well, as i wanted to use an array in the program later on.

Here is my main method.

```
 import java.math.*;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;


public class labBookFiftyFour
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int shift = -1;
    double pRate = -2;
    String name = " ";
    String number = " ";
    String date = " ";

        while(shift < 0 || pRate < 0 )
            {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the shift, 1 for day, 2 for night");
                    if(myInput.hasNextInt()){
                        System.out.println("you entered a number for the shift");
                        shift = myInput.nextInt();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Please enter the hourly pay Rate");
                    if(myInput.hasNextDouble()){
                        System.out.println("you entered a number for the pay Rate");
                        pRate = myInput.nextDouble();
                    }
                    else if (myInput.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a proper value");
                        myInput.next();
                      } else {
                        System.err.println("No more input");
                        System.exit(1);
                      }
            }
                myInput.nextLine(); //consume newLine
                    System.out.println("Please enter the employees name");
                   name = myInput.nextLine();                                         //use your isValid method
                    if(isValid(name))
                    {
                        System.out.println("your value you entered is correct 0-9 or a - z  ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Please enter the employee number");
                    number = myInput.nextLine();                                         //use your isValid method
                    if(isValid(number))
                    {
                        System.out.println("your value you entered is correct 0-9 or a - z  ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Please enter current date in XXYYZZZZ format, X is day, Y is month, Z is year");
                    date = myInput.nextLine();                                         //use your isValid method
                    if(isValid(date))
                    {
                        System.out.println("your value you entered is correct 0-9 or a - z  ");
                    }

            ProductionWorker myWorker = new ProductionWorker(shift, pRate, name, number, date);  //int day and night , double payRate
            System.out.println("THis is the shift " + myWorker.getShift() + " This is the pay Rate " + myWorker.getPRate() + " " + myWorker.getName()
             + " " + myWorker.getNumber() + " " + myWorker.getDate());
}
//Made this method for testing String input for 0-9 or a - z values , put AFTER main method, but before end of class
                public static boolean isValid(String stringName) //This method has to be static, for some reason?
                {
                    System.out.println("cat" + stringName.length() + stringName.charAt(0));
                    boolean flag = true;
                    int index = 0;
                while(index < stringName.length())
                {
                    if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(stringName.charAt(index)))
                    {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    ++index;
                }
                    return flag;
                }
}
```

Here is my employeeOne. java Superclass

```
public class employeeOne
{
private String name;

private String number;

private String date;

public employeeOne(String name, String number, String date)
{
    this.name = name;

    this.number = number;

    this.date = date;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getNumber()
{
    return number;
}

public String getDate()
{
    return date;
}

}
```

Here is my ProductionWorker.java subclass, which extends employeeOne

```
    public class ProductionWorker extends employeeOne
{
private int shift; //shift represents day or night, day = 1, night  = 2

private double pRate; //hourly pay rate

public ProductionWorker(int shift, double pRate, String name, String number, String date)
{
    super(name, number, date);

    this.shift = shift;

    if(this.shift >= 3 || this.shift <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("You entered an out of bounds shift date, enter 1 for day or 2 for night, else shift will be day");
        this.shift = 1;
    }
        this.pRate = pRate;

    boolean goodSoFar = true;
    int indexNum = 0;
    int indexDate = 0;

    if(name.length() <= 10 && number.length() <= 4 && date.length() < 9 )
    {
        goodSoFar = true;
    }
    else
    {
        goodSoFar = false;
    }

    while(goodSoFar && indexNum < 3) //XXXL  XXX digits 1-9, L is a letter A -M
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(number.charAt(indexNum)))
        {
            goodSoFar = true;
        }
        else
        {
            goodSoFar = false;
        }
        ++indexNum;
    }

    while(goodSoFar && indexNum < 4)
    {
        if(Character.isLetter(number.charAt(indexNum)))
        {
            goodSoFar = true;
        }
        else if(Character.isDigit(number.charAt(indexNum)))
        {
            goodSoFar = false;
        }
        else if(Character.isDigit(number.charAt(indexNum)) == false && Character.isLetter(number.charAt(indexNum)) == false)
        {
            goodSoFar = false;
        }

        ++indexNum;
    }
    int[] dateValues = new int[date.length()];
    while(goodSoFar && indexDate <= date.length())  //XXYYZZZZ
    {
        System.out.println("" + date.length() + indexDate + " " + date.charAt(indexDate));

        if(Character.isDigit(date.charAt(indexDate)))
        {
             dateValues[indexDate] = Character.getNumericValue(date.charAt(indexDate));
                System.out.println("value of array is " + dateValues[indexDate]);
        ++indexDate;
        }
        else
        {
            goodSoFar = false;
        }
    }
    if(goodSoFar)
    {
        System.out.println("your input is good so far");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("your input is wrong for name or number or date");
    }
}
public int getShift()
{
    return shift;
}

public double getPRate()
{
    return pRate;
}

}
```

Comment: What is line 66 of `ProductionWorker.java`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
while(goodSoFar && indexDate <= date.length())  //XXYYZZZZ
```

you must Change to

```
while(goodSoFar && indexDate < date.length())  //XXYYZZZZ
                            ^^^
```

Because  the sting is an char Array starting at Position Zero.

Comment: Thanks hexafraction and Jens